# Pandas: Conditional str.split

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am wondering how I might best split strings conditionally in a data frame so the right values get to the right columns. Consider the following when the length of the string varies. Time is in hours, minutes, seconds.

```
time = ['22:35', '1:20:20']
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time})
df
    time
0   22:35
1   1:20:20
```

Tried variations of this:

```
for i in df['time']:
    if len(i) == 5:
        df[['minutes', 'seconds']] = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
    if len(i) == 7:
        df[['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']] = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
```

Comment: Whenever possible, you should always normalize your input data to work with standardized date and/or time: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html & https://strftime.org/ This will much simplify things.

Comment: series.str.extract with regex is your friend:)

Answer (score 0):

Might not be such an elegant answer but I believe this works:

```
time = ['22:35', '1:20:20']

templist = [item.split(":") for item in time]

templist2 = []
for item in templist:
    if len(item) == 3:
        thisdict = {
            "hours": item[0],
            "minutes": item[1],
            "seconds": item[2]
        }
        templist2.append(thisdict)
    elif len(item) == 2:
        thisdict = {
            "hours": "0",
            "minutes": item[0],
            "seconds": item[1]
        }
        templist2.append(thisdict)
    elif len(item) == 1:
        thisdict = {
            "hours": "0",
            "minutes": "0",
            "seconds": item[0]
        }
        templist2.append(thisdict)

df = pd.DataFrame(templist2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mark Wang and @s.k, but here's something that might work for you:

```
import datetime

def time_converter(s):
    nb_semicolons = s.count(':')
    if nb_semicolons == 1:
        form = '%M:%S'
    if nb_semicolons == 2:
        form = '%H:%M:%S'
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, form).time()

df['time2'] = df['time'].apply(time_converter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be easier:

```
import pandas as pd
time = ['22:35', '1:20:20']
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time})

def f1(x):
    if len(x) == 5:
        x = '0:' + x
    return x

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(f1)
df[['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']] = df['time'].str.split(':', expand=True)
df

    time    hours   minutes seconds
0   0:22:35 0         22     35
1   1:20:20 1         20     20
```